# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: “9:30 AM” (at offset 5)

Tags: java, android, datetime, datetime-format

I want to compare two time based so i just convert time to date.

i have parse time like this:

```
 SimpleDateFormat h_mm_a = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
 Date d1 = h_mm_a.parse(txtTimeFrom.getText().toString());
 Date d2 =  h_mm_a.parse(txtTimeTo.getText().toString());
 if(d1.compareTo(d2)<0){
     ....................
 }
 else{
     Toast.makeText(ExecutiveRouteTracking.this,"Invalid Time",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

It will throw exception like

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: “9:30 AM” (at offset 5)
```

Can any one help me to solve problem to compare two time?

Answer (score 0):

Try with Joda Time

```
    String currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date());

    DateTimeFormatter parseFormat = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("HH:mm").toFormatter();

    LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(currentTime, parseFormat);
    LocalTime limit = new LocalTime("14:00");
    return localTime.isAfter(limit);
```

Comment: Will not work if OP has Java 7 or less

Comment: @Akshay Since when is Joda limited to Java 8?

Comment: Oops...it is added in jdk 8..DateTimeFormatter class

Comment: But Joda is not needed to parse a american format time... luckily Java can manage this itself.

Comment: Joda-Time is an option. I believe there is a better one. The Joda-Time home page says “Users are now asked to migrate to `java.time` (JSR-310).” But is JSR-310 available in Android? Indeed! See [this question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), please.